# images not getting loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to load a bunch of png images that are in a folder in my project. I'm using a function that takes in an array of strings that signify the name of the actual images.

The actual html that comes up in the console seems correct, however the images don't get loaded. The weird thing is, if I hard code in the html with the src of one of the images, the src in the inspector comes up as 'name.93439.png' with random numbers in between the name and the file extension, and the image shows up. But the source I am injecting in the javascript using template strings is no different than what I am putting into the html when I hard code it.

So is there something I'm missing here with loading images? Why does hard coding it in work, but when I try using JS it doesn't give the same results? Code below:

FILE STRUCTURE:

```
index.html
/src
  index.js
  /assets
    /images
      ...{all of the images}.png
```

```
function loadImages(names) {
    names.forEach((name) => {
        let image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = `src/assets/images/${name}.png`;

        let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.appendChild(image);
        document.getElementById('images').appendChild(newDiv);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your folder structure is not quite clear

Comment: That sounds like you're using some builder (parcel, webpack, browserify?) for your project (hashed paths), which builder is it and how does your build script look like. Also how do you reference your js file in your html.

Comment: @OlivierKrull I'm using parcel. And I just have a script tag before the end of the body tag.

Comment: This happens because parcel hashes your assets during building. When executing the js, `${name}` is not aware of the (parcel) hash and therefore doen't finds the correct file. Try to take out the assets from the build process and copy them to your `dist` folder. So the assets file names do not get hashed. (Or something similar is happening). Please check if the image names are also hashed when you don't hard code the in the html.

Comment: @OlivierKrull Ahhh I see. Okay, that worked! Thanks so much!

Comment: You're welcome, added answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because parcel hashes your assets during building. When executing the js, `${name}` is not aware of the (parcel) hash and therefore doesn't finds the correct file. Try to take out the assets from the build process and copy them to your `dist` folder (you'll probably want to automate this at some point). So the assets file names do not get hashed.